# How to make mat-checkbox unclickable in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can make my `mat-checkbox` disabled, but want to maintain the same css that it has when being enabled. The checkbox will be checked when its input text has a value, like I did here below:

```
<mat-checkbox [disableRipple]="true" [checked]="option.controls.text.value !== ''">
  <input #infoBox matInput formControlName="info" class="input-other" maxlength="100" type="text" [value]="option.controls.text.value">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: If the posted answer doesn't help you then please provide bit more description, *What type of CSS it has?* *Do you want to disable only click event?*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the user should never be able to toggle the checkbox manually. Instead it will be toggle programmatically depending on the input value.

You can very simply prevent the default `click` behavior, so nothing happens when the checkbox is clicked:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="infoBox.value !== ''"
              [disableRipple]="true"
              (click)="$event.preventDefault()">

  <input #infoBox matInput type="text">

</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: it still can be checked by pressing blankspace on it

Comment: you can also add `style="cursor: unset"` to not get that pointer cursor

Answer (score 19):

This way it also becomes not focusable and you won't be able to check it using the keyboard.

```js
    <mat-checkbox
        [checked]="state"
        [class.mat-checkbox-disabled]="false"
        disabled>
    </mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: in later versions of angular material its  [class.mat-mdc-checkbox-disabled]="true"

Answer (score 9):

use the **disabled** attribute

```
 <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkboxvalue" [disabled]="true"/>
```

or

```
<mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkboxvalue" disabled/>
```

Refer [Example](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css property on checkbox element.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="checked"
              (click)="change()">
```

JS file:

```
change(){
checked=true;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not provide a good solution to the question and there is no explaination for the code